# C - while operator in for loop initializer

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, comma-operator

Why I cannot write smthng like this?

```
int i, size;
int *arr;
...
for(i = size - 1, while(arr[i] == 0) i--; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

Comment: For the same reason you can't write a lot of things - it's not valid C syntax.

Comment: Short answer - because the language grammar won't allow it; the control expressions in a `for` statement cannot be other *statements*.  As for *why* the grammar is that way, you'd have to ask Dennis Ritchie, and he's not around anymore.

Comment: Because the language only allows *expressions* and not statements.

Comment: Read about `for` loop syntax. `for ( expression; expression; expression ) statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just no valid syntax in C.

A Solution for what you want might be:

```
int i, size;
int *arr;
...
for(i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] == 0)
        continue;
    ...
}
```